# How start multiple video automatically in Android app (offline)

Tags: android, eclipse, video, android-intent, android-videoview

Good morning, Ive create an activity with a videoview that start automatically and load a video from uri in loop mode.
How can I load 2 or three video in loop mode?
For example load for from Uri(xxx1, xxx2, xxx3)?
Thaks in advance

Comment: You'd have multiple video views, each loading their own video.

Comment: Ok, but how can i start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can either create a RecyclerView or ListView or ScrollView and respective Adapter or Child video views.

Have a list of video Uris in Uri[] or ArrayList

Call these in respective getView or for(Uri uri : mUris) loop

Here is a single instance to play a video

```
 private void playVideo(Uri uri) {

        //set the media controller buttons
        if (mediaControls == null) {
            mediaControls = new MediaController(AndroidVideoViewExample.this);
        }

        //initialize the VideoView
        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);


        try {
            //set the media controller in the VideoView
            myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);

            //set the uri of the video to be played
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //we also set an setOnPreparedListener in order to know when the video file is ready for playback
        myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // close the progress bar and play the video
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //if we have a position on savedInstanceState, the video playback should start from here
                myVideoView.seekTo(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    myVideoView.start();
                } else {
                    //if we come from a resumed activity, video playback will be paused
                    myVideoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: isn't possible to call in same VideoView, when finish first video, another video? My idea was use same videoview and when finish first video call another uri..

Comment: videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { //finish(); } });

Comment: I've solved with this code but it don't restart from first:    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

         @Override
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
         {
             Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + videoArray[3]);
             videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
             videoView.start();
         }
     });

Comment: Just try this. videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

         @Override
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
         {
             videoView.start();
         }
     });

Comment: Without these strings?  Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + videoArray[3]); videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

Comment: Sorry. The above one helps you to play the same video in a loop. If you want to play a different video then whatever you said above is right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137053/discussion-between-ormet-and-albeee).